# How to re order the serial number after remove delete the row in php

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

[image: here i tried to delete the 4th roe and added a next one. but it is not showing properly]

Here is my code, and i tried to delete one row and added a new one.It's deleting record from data base, after deleted recording I want to display remain data and remove particular row in table. but its not seems proper. please help some one

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<$this->labNumber; $i++):
                $divlabcapdisp="divlabcap_".$i;
                $divlabcoursedispdisp="divlabcoursedisp_".$i;
                ?>
                <div class="form-group clone_field_2">
                    <div class="content-div">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <label class="control-label">Lab <?=$i+1?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <?=$this->deliverelement($this->labElement[$i])?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <?=$this->deliverelement($this->labtypeElement[$i])?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div style="display:<?php if($this->$divlabcapdisp==OT_YES):?>inline<?php else:?>none<?php endif;?>">
                                <?=$this->deliverelement($this->labcapElement[$i])?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div style="display:<?php if($this->$divlabcoursedispdisp==OT_YES):?>inline<?php else:?>none<?php endif;?>">
                                <?=$this->deliverelement($this->labcourseElement[$i])?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 text-red" <?php if($i==0):?>style="display:none;"<?php endif;?>>
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o fa-lg" onClick="deleteButton1(this,'clone_field_2')"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and the onclick function is

```
function deleteButton1(link,clonefield)
{
    var rowCount = $('.'+clonefield).length;
    var minCount = 1;

    if(rowCount > minCount)
    {
        $(link).closest('.'+clonefield).remove();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You cannot delete the last row");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

closest() works on ancestor tree What you're looking for is **parent()**

Replace this

```
if(rowCount > minCount)
    {
        $(link).closest('.'+clonefield).remove();
    }
```

with

```
  if(rowCount > minCount)
        {
            $(link).parent('div').parent('div').fadeOut(200, function() { $(link).remove(); });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but still its not getting the ordered serial number.

Comment: @SKM which ordered number do you want ?

Comment: Now its not replacing the deleted id when i am deleting a middle row. Thanks in advance @Saad Suri

Comment: For that you need to make a counter like var i =1; and when you add the row increment i through i++, and when you're deleting the row do i-- so you and pass that to id so you won't get orphan element.